# what would be the best approach to generate JWT token for server to server communications?

Tags: authentication, jwt, token, microservices

I am planning to develop an authentication service which generates and validates the JWT token for incoming requests.

What would be the best challenge mechanism which could be employed to generate the JWT token? Since the request is generated from an applicaiton and not an end-user, username/password combination is ruled out in this case.

I am looking to explore on areas like generation of tokens based on keystore. Any inputs would be highly welcomed.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: First, you should include which programming language you plan to use.  Most major languages (e.g. Java, JavaScript, Python) already have fairly robust libraries which can handle the plumbing for JWT.  So, you should look into using one of them.

Comment: Many thanks for your response Tim. I'm planning to use Java. could you please point me to few libraries if you have come across?

Comment: See here: https://stormpath.com/blog/beginners-guide-jwts-in-java